# How to use Jquery Validator to validate a number with precision requirement

Tags: jquery, numbers, precision, validation

Using Jquery validator.
We are trying to create a customized method to validate a currency number with precision requirement. This method actually will be an enhancement of the existing number validate method, but we want to limit its precision. For example, if we want to allow the precision to be up to 2 digit.
For example:

1. 1,000.00/true
2. 1,000.0/true
3. 1,000/true
4. -1,000.00/true
5. 1,000.001/false

   Updated: 
   the existing number validate function is below:

   /^-?(?:\d+|\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})+)(?:.\d+)?$/

How to add the precision requirement?Can anybody help me on this? Thanks.

Comment: Your regex works assuming there is no commas placed in the number - which will be the case for a user typing it in. You may want to expand `{1,3}` though as your example has a 4 digit number.

Answer (score -1):

```
/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(\.\d{2}))/g, "$1,"
```